# Slope analysis on Terrain data using WhiteBox GAT?

Tags: area, whitebox-gat

How do I find out the Slope of "best fit to the sectoral terrain" using WhiteBox GAT?

Here are the details about the area of calculation.

We have a reference point, from the reference point our sectoral area could be around 1000m with the sector range starts from 220 degree to 300 degree. I wanted to calculate the "best fit to the sectoral area between 220 degree to 300 degree with the length of 1000m".

What I did so far is, I calculated the slope of the whole terrain but I can't limit the slope area within 1000m with 220 deg to 300 degree. Again I don't know how to calculate the "best fit" of the slope for the sectoral plane.

This helps to finish this one.

[image]